# Looping JQuery for carousel indicators in <ol>

Tags: jquery

I am very much a novice at JQuery and I have a carousel that infinitely loops my images so I wanted to add indicators to my page to show how many images are in my carousel.  I managed to manipulate some JQuery code which cycles through my ordered list with a class named "carousel-indicators" meanwhile removing and adding the class 'active'.  This works great and I have JQuery script linked to both my "#mid_left_arrow img" and "#mid_right_arrow img" on click.  I just can't get it where when I reach the last indicator that it "loops" back around to the first indicator and adds the class "active" and vice versa for going in reverse where I reach the first indicator then it loops back to the last indicator and adds the class "active".  I know this is a very novice question, so I apologize for that… anyway here is the JQuery that I used:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
         $('#mid_right_arrow img').click(function () {
       var $active = $('.carousel-indicators .active');
    var $next = $active.next();
    $next.addClass('active');
    $active.removeClass('active');
 });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
         $('#mid_left_arrow img').click(function () {
       var $active = $('.carousel-indicators .active');
    var $prev = $active.prev();
    $prev.addClass('active');
    $active.removeClass('active');
 });
});
</script>
```

and this is the html for my ordered list:

```html
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li class="active">•</li>
    <li class="">•</li>
    <li class="">•</li>
    <li class="">•</li>
    <li class="">•</li>
    <li class="">•</li>
    <li class="">•</li>
    <li class="">•</li>
    <li class="">•</li>
    <li class="">•</li>
    <li class="">•</li>
    <li class="">•</li>
    <li class="">•</li>
    <li class="">•</li>
    <li class="">•</li>
  </ol>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop using the below code. [DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/6jxx9xsL/1/)

```
$('#mid_left_arrow img').click(function() {
  var $active = $('.carousel-indicators .active');
  var $prev = $active.prev();

  // check if you have a valid li, otherwise select the last li
  if ($prev.length == 0) {
    $prev = $('.carousel-indicators li').last();
  }
  $prev.addClass('active');
  $active.removeClass('active');
});

$('#mid_right_arrow img').click(function() {
  var $active = $('.carousel-indicators .active');
  var $next = $active.next();

  // check if you have a valid li, otherwise select the first li
  if ($next.length == 0) {
    $next = $('.carousel-indicators li').first();
  }

  $next.addClass('active');
  $active.removeClass('active');
});
```

**Note: You don't have to write document.ready function for every single event. Write it once & inside it you can write all your events.**

Comment: Krishna… I tried this code and it works perfectly.  Thank you very much for answering my novice question.  I knew I was close but I just needed a little help.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the selected element is the last element or not with `$(this).is(':last-child')`. Similarly with `first-child`. You can then define how to process when at the edges.

You can check whether the next element is the last element or not beforehand with `.next().length`. When it equals 0, there is no next element (you're at the last already).

Comment: noctrnal… thank you very much for your reply.  I am very much a novice and I thank anyone for their guidance.  Thank you.

Comment: You are very welcome. Looks like Krishna helped ya with a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to check if you're on the last child, and if so, look at the first element in the list.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#mid_right_arrow img').click(function () {
        var $active = $('.carousel-indicators .active');
        var $next = $active.next();
        if ($next.length == 0) {
           $next = $active.siblings().first();
        }
        $next.addClass('active');
        $active.removeClass('active');
});
```

});

As a style comment, by the way, there is no need to add dollar signs to the front of your variables. That's more of a PHP thing.

Comment: this doesn't work. If you want it to work change it to `$next = $active.siblings().first();`

Comment: Cidolfas… Thank you for your reply.  I knew I was close but I just needed a little help.  I am a novice obviously so I thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: My pleasure! @Krishna - thanks for the fix, I'll edit it.